# Rolling Sum in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to find the sum of (each row + 3) subsequent rows.  Here is the code I'm using to get this accomplished: `df_sum_row_and_3_subsequent_rows = df.iloc[::-1].rolling(4, min_periods=1).sum().sum(axis=1).iloc[::-1]`
Is there a better way of doing this?

Here is the DataFrame that I'm using:

```
                     NBL  NBT  NBR  SBL  SBT  SBR  EBL  EBT  EBR  WBL  WBT  WBR
DATETIME                                                                       
2020-01-01 10:00:00    9    2   28    8    6    5    4   92    9   21  124    5
2020-01-01 10:15:00   13    0   24   12    2    7    5   91    7   20  123   11
2020-01-01 10:30:00    5    1   16   10    2    4    9  115   12   21  118    9
2020-01-01 10:45:00   10    5   25    9    2    6    5  114    6   25  128   13
2020-01-01 11:00:00   11    4   28   11    3    7    7  110    8   30  126   10
2020-01-01 11:15:00    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
2020-01-01 11:30:00    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
2020-01-01 11:45:00    8    5   24   12   10   12   14  130   18   42  154   17
2020-01-01 12:00:00   14    5   29   15    1   17    4  138   17   44  141    9
2020-01-01 12:15:00   12    4   45   13    3   13   13  147   27   47  134   13
```

Comment: Seems fine to me. There are other ways, like manually shifting, but I doubt it's any simpler or more efficient. You can also use strides, but that can get a bit opaque. You may not need the final `.iloc[::-1]`; if you're going to assign the result back pandas will align on index anyway.

Comment: What is the point of `.iloc[::-1]`?

Comment: @DYZ it's because rolling is always a backward looking (row, row-1, row-2, ...) (AFAIK there' no way to simply change that...) so to do a forward rolling (row, row+1, row+2, ...) the simplest way is to reverse the order before rolling.

Comment: @ALollz You can shift the results by 3 to the same effect.